# How can I use buttons generated from a loop to call a function with changing parameters?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am facing an issue while creating tables for different orders with their respective products and checkboxes for product preparation.

I have created buttons using a loop that will call a function to check the checkboxes and send SQL commands to the database. However, the problem comes when there are multiple orders with different order IDs but all the buttons show the same order ID and total amount of products.

As a result, the SQL command is sent to the same item, even though the order ID and the total amount of products change in the code due to the loop that goes through an array of order IDs and products.

I wasn't able to find any solutions on the internet for my problem. I even tried using ChatGPT and it couldn't solve my problem.

I would appreciate some assistance for my problem.

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once "process_orders.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Commande Client</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        if ($number_of_orders == 0)
        {
            ?>

            <h1>Aucun panier en cours</h1>

            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>

            <h1>Traitement des paniers</h1>

            <?php

            for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_orders; $i++) 
            {
                ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3"><?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getName(); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Produit</th>
                        <th>Quantité</th>
                        <th><?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_date(); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php

                    for ($j = 0; $j < $customerOrder[$i]->getTotalProducts(); $j++)
                    {
                        $product_name = $customerOrder[$i]->getProductName($j);
                        $customer_products_quantity = $customerOrder[$i]->getProductQuantity($j);
                    
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $product_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $customer_products_quantity; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_id();?>"  value="<?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getProductId($j);?>" id=<?php echo $j?> <?php if($customerOrder[$i]->getProductAvailable($j)) { echo "checked"; } ?>></td>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3">
                            <button onclick="updateNonManquant(<?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getOrder_id() ?>, <?php echo $customerOrder[$i]->getTotalProducts() ?>)">Valider</button> <!-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM -->
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                
                <br> <br>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

js file

```
function updateNonManquant(order_id, totalProducts) {
    for (let i = 0; i < totalProducts; i++) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = "db_query.php";
        var sql;

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var checkbox = document.getElementById(i);
        var id_Products = checkbox.value;
        var button_name = checkbox.name;
        
        alert(button_name + " " + order_id);

        if (button_name == order_id) {
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                sql = `UPDATE article SET non_manquant = 1 WHERE id = ${id_Products} AND num_commande = ${order_id}`;

                xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));
            } else {     
                sql = `UPDATE article SET non_manquant = 0 WHERE id = ${id_Products} AND num_commande = ${order_id}`;
                
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify({sql: sql}));
            }
            alert(id_Products);
        }
    }
    location.reload();
}
```

db_query file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "site_e-commerce";

$sql = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"))->sql;

$link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "SQL command executed successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error executing SQL command: " . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

[items in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MauT7.png)